# Document event bubbling works on Firefox but not Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, event-handling, addeventlistener, dom-events

Implemented a document wide click event bubble capture so that I might have one function for all button clicks. However, this works fine in Firefox but not in other browsers (Chrome), where you don't get the alert triggered.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

    var preventClickAction = false;

    // get clicked element
    var clickedElem = event.target;

    // mobile button click
    if(clickedElem.matches("#mobile-menu-button")){
        alert();

        preventClickAction = true;
    }

    if(preventClickAction){
        event.preventDefault();
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: An id should be unique on the DOM. For this example, it's more correct to use a specific class name or data attribute for the selector into matches function

Comment: Have you tried `webkitMatchesSelector`? According to the compat table in MDN it should work for both.

Comment: I have the MDN polyfil added to my code so should be working

Comment: Please provide the DOM markup with which you are trying this, as well as where exactly you are clicking.

Comment: The console.log prints out either the  button child SVG or the SVG's child <line> elements and not the button itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine for me in FireFox. Here's a demo: https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/WPxjVR

There are a few problems/caveats, though.

1. If there's an element inside your element, `matches()` won't work because the clicked element is the inner element. In this case, you'd need to use `closest()`, which checks if the selector has *or is within* the selector. Here's another demo: https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/pGbPmw
2. Both `matches()` and `closest()` need polyfills. They work great in newer browsers, but older ones have spotty support. Here's [one for `matches()`](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/matches/), and [one for `closest()`](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/closest/). Alternatively, you can use a service like https://polyfill.io to handle this automatically.
3. In Firefox, right-clicks fire the `click` event. No other browser behaves this way, so I believe this is a bug. FF proponents often say this is just adhering to spec, but there's a special event for right-click events, so... At any rate, you can avoid this quirk by attaching your `click` event to the `document.documentElement` instead.
4. Your listener callback is suboptimally written. The whole thing can be written like this:

   ```js
   document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

       // mobile button click
       if(event.target.closest("#mobile-menu-button")){
           alert();
           event.preventDefault();
       }

   }, false);
   ```

   There's no need to set `event.target` to a variable, nor do you need to set a separate variable to decide if you should `preventDefault()` or not. Just put it in your `if` statement for the selector. Here's another demo: https://codepen.io/cferdinandi/pen/wNWeMo

Comment: Thank you Chris! This is ace. However my code WAS working in FF but not other browsers, is this because of the element inside. This being the case, it seems that it's not really bubbling per say, but simply stopping on the lowest element clicked..?

Comment: Ah, ok, so... this is a weird technical thing with how event bubbling works.

The event bubbles all the way up to the top of the DOM. Otherwise, adding your listener to the `document` wouldn't work. BUT... the `event.target` never changes, and is always the element that triggered the event. Otherwise, event delegation would never actually work.

Comment: still confused but thanks. I thought that as it bubbles up it literally would look at each node up the tree till it reached the document, it appears it only hits the item clicked, thus the need for closet() not matches() - I guess i still dont really know what the point of doing it this way is then :( it doesnt really seem to bubble at all in my mind

Comment: The event listener, in your case, is attached on the `document`. First it hits the clicked element, then it's parent, then it's parent, until it reaches the `document` and your event listener callback fires.

But for each level it bubbles up, `event.target` is always the element that triggered the event in the first place. If you clicked on an element inside your desired element, that's the `event.target` and `matches()` will fail.

Comment: ok so my actual question is this: if "then it's parent, then it's parent, until it reaches the document" how do you capture those events if event.target is only lowest node and nothing inbetween?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to do. If you wanted to capture an event on a higher element, you'd want to change the selector for `if (matches())` or `if (closest())`. There's also an `event.path` property that will give you the entire bubble chain, but bear in mind that it includes everything up to the element you're listening on, in this case the `document`.

Comment: Sorry Chris think I thought the method of catching clickes worked like this (but obviously doesn't): doc clicked -> lowest or highest node runs as event in function dpending on bubble mode true or false -> (lets say lowest node), then the next node runs code, and the next and the next till the top node e.g. the doc. So matches() would work in this case as each node would run against it and return the node that (in my case) the parent of the click or parents parent.... this to me is what I thought was happening.